# Referring to NSPersistentStore instances created in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, appdelegate, nspersistentstore

I modified the boilerplate core data stack code you get with a core data application to add two `NSPersistentStore`s to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` instead of just one.

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DB", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    var error: NSError? = nil

    let firstStoreURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("first-store.sqlite")
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: firstStoreURL, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil        
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    let secondStoreURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("second-store.sqlite")
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: secondStoreURL, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support
func saveContext() {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {            
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

I need to specify the store when adding `NSManagedObject` objects like below.

```
let someObject = NSManagedObject(entity: "someEntity", insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
context.assignObject(someObject, toPersistentStore: <store instance>)
```

And specifying the stores which I need to fetch data from like this.

```
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("someEntity", inManagedObjectContext: context)

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
fetchRequest.affectedStores = [<store instance>]
```

My question is how can I get a reference to those `NSPersistentStore`s created in the AppDelegate?

Just to be clear, I already know how to get a reference to the AppDelegate itself.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
```

It's the getting the `NSPersistentStore` part is where I'm stuck.

---

I tried creating it as a separate property in the AppDelegat like this but I don't know how to call it/add it from `persistentStoreCoordinator`.

```
var firstStore: NSPersistentStore {
    var store: NSPersistentStore!
    if let coordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator {
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("first-store.sqlite")
        var error: NSError?
        store = coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error)!
    }
    return store
}
```

Besides whenever I call this property, wouldn't it add a new instance of a store to the coordinator?

Comment: @LordZsolt Hi, I updated my question with a similar attempt I took but I'm kinda stuck in it too.

Comment: Yes, that would add a new instance of store into the coordinator. But you could limit the number of stores by doing something like `[persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores count]`

Comment: Though I don't understand why you'd want two persistent stores. Maybe two Coordinators...

Comment: Isn't that only returns the number of persistent stores in that coordinator? It's simply a read-only property.

Comment: Well yes, if the count is greater than 2, it means you already have 2 and you don't add a new one. Though I still don't understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: So exactly why are you wanting to use two instances of `NSPersistentStore`?

Comment: In one of my apps, I need one store to persist some data permanently while another store to save another data set temporarily for a short period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `persistentStores` [property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator/persistentStores) on `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` you can use for this purpose. It returns an array of (presumably) `NSPersistentStore` instances.

```
// Get the first store, assuming it exists
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let firstStore = appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores[0] as NSPersistentStore
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the reference of property in app delegate you will need to get app delegate reference first by doing so:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
```

and then you can get and use any property from your appDelegate object

```
let someObject = NSManagedObject(entity: "someEntity",insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
context.assignObject(someObject, toPersistentStore: appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Yes, I know how to get the AppDelegate's reference. I'm just not sure how to separate the `NSPersistentStore` as a property. I updated my question with my attempt.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `NSPersistentStore` as a property? . I think `appDelegate. persistentStoreCoordinator` will do that for you